# PostgreSQL Point-In-Time Recovery Getting Error with No valid checkpoint record

Tags: postgresql, point-in-time-recovery

I am trying to perform a Point-In-Time Recovery using the WAL_ARCHIVE process. The archive command is added to the postgresql.conf file and I can see the WAL being archived in the backup-archive directory. When I try to start the service I get `PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record`

I am using the below step-by-step process.

1. low level api basebackup
   `SELECT pg_start_backup('label', true, false);`
2. copying the data directory of my cluster
   `tar -zcvpf basebkPostgres20230110New.tgz /PostgreSQL/13/data`
3. closing my basebackup
   `SELECT * FROM pg_stop_backup(false, true);`
4. Stopping the postgres service
5. Removing the current's cluster data directory
6. Restoring the backed up data directory
7. Removing the contents of the pg_wal directory
8. Setting the restore_command in the postgresql.conf file
9. Starting the postgres service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `backup_label` file and `recovery.signal`. You have to capture the result of `pg_stop_backup` (or `pg_backup_stop` from v15 on) and create `backup_label` from the contents. That file has to be in the restored data directory. Also, you have to create `recovery.signal` in the data directory, so that PostgreSQL starts in archive recovery mode and reads your `restore_command`.

Without `restore_command`, PostgreSQL uses the WAL in `pg_wal`, which is empty. Without `backup_label`, PostgreSQL thinks that it can recover from the checkpoint indicated by the control file `pg_control`. Even if that worked, the result would be a corrupted database, since you have to recover from the start of the backup.

`recovery.signal` is documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-PITR-RECOVERY) (step 7), and `backup_label` is documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/continuous-archiving.html#BACKUP-LOWLEVEL-BASE-BACKUP) (step 4).

Comment: Thank you very much @laurenz-albe . I was actually following the documentation but I believe the non-exclusive backup does not clarify the `backup_label` nor the `recovery.signal` part.

Comment: I believe otherwise and have added pointers to the documentation.